# RelativeLayout, collapse/expand without resizing child height

Tags: android, animation

I have a toolbar made with a RelativeLayout containing ImageButtons. I'd like to collapse/expand this RelativeLayout without modifying buttons height during the animation. Actually, the buttons are automatically changing their height during the animation to match the parent height. It makes the animation laggy and not as I'd like.

The layout

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tweet_toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tweet_toolbar_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#858585">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tweet_toolbar_reply"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tweet_toolbar_height"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gray_darker"
        android:src="@drawable/tweet_icon_toolbar_reply"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The animation

```
    private void collapseToolbar() {
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mToolbarContainer, VIEW_LAYOUT_HEIGHT, mToolbarHeight, 0);
    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            mToolbarContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    animator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
    animator.start();
}

Property<View, Integer> VIEW_LAYOUT_HEIGHT = new Property<View, Integer>(Integer.class, "viewLayoutHeight") {

    public void set(View object, Integer value) {
        object.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
        object.requestLayout();
    }

    public Integer get(View object) {
        return object.getLayoutParams().height;
    }
};
```

Does anyone know how to achieve it?